# Calling user-defined C functions in inline assembly

Tags: c++, c, assembly, inline-assembly

Let's say I have this:

```
extern "C" {
void foo1();
void foo2();
};
void foo1() 
{
__asm
    {
       ; some stuff

       ; some other 
    }
}

  void foo2() 
  {
    __asm 
        {
              ;some other stuff
              call __foo1

        }
  }
```

I know that in a regular .asm program you would be reuqired to say extrn __fucntionName, but this is inline assembly, can user defined functions can be called like this in inline assembly? and how?
I use VS2008.

Comment: Your example compiles in VS if `call foo2`

Comment: OK, right. Much simpler, now.

Comment: You should have specified the compiler, but seems Roman made a lucky guess....

Comment: This is wildly compiler specific. Inline assembly is not covered within the standard.

Comment: @IxChan he edited post to include compiler name

Answer (score 0):

Calling a C function from assembler is possible. Syntax of this call depends on compiler you use. Usually there are diferences in how function names look in assembly and vice versa.